# MongoDB shared memory usage

Tags: mongodb, memory

I was looking at the top output on a dedicated mongo machine with 16gb of ram and I noticed that the memory consumed by the mongod process was split 7.5gb RES and 7.5gb SHR. What is 7.5gb used for in SHR memory? Does this mean that mongodb actually has only 7.5gb available for mem-mapping the data?